# Get input from text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to show latitude and longitude in textarea. What seems to be the wrong in this code? Thank you

**HTML :**

```
  Locations:
  <select name="ctrTitles" id="ctrTitles">
    <option value="1">School</option>
    <option value="2">Office</option>

  </select>

  <textarea name="inputList" id="inputList" cols="50" rows="5" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Proses" onclick="clickedAddList()">
  <input id="button2" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="directions(1, false, false, false, false)">
 <input id='button3' type='button' value='Reset' onclick='startOver()'>
```

**JS:**

```
var centerLocations = {}

text1: -9.683075, 124.1241341 - 10.258829, 123.553435 - 10.1965777, 123.5305067,
  text2: -9.853080, 124.268283 - 10.115900, 123.809843 - 9.874031, 124.249636
};

$('#ctrTitles').change(function() {
  $("inputList").val(centerLocations["text" + this.value]);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `#` in

```
$("inputList").val(centerLocations["text" + this.value]);
```

Should be

```
$("#inputList").val(centerLocations["text" + this.value]);
```

Also, the object `centerLocations` is not defined correctly.
The values should be wrapped in quotes.

Should be as follow:

```
var centerLocations = {
    text1: '-9.683075, 124.1241341 - 10.258829, 123.553435 - 10.1965777, 123.5305067',
    text2: '-9.853080, 124.268283 - 10.115900, 123.809843 - 9.874031, 124.249636'
};
```

**Demo**

```js
var centerLocations = {
  text1: '-9.683075, 124.1241341 - 10.258829, 123.553435 - 10.1965777, 123.5305067',
  text2: '-9.853080, 124.268283 - 10.115900, 123.809843 - 9.874031, 124.249636'
};

$('#ctrTitles').change(function() {
  $("#inputList").val(centerLocations["text" + this.value]);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Locations:
<select name="ctrTitles" id="ctrTitles">
  <option value="1">School</option>
  <option value="2">Office</option>
</select>

<textarea name="inputList" id="inputList" cols="50" rows="5" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Proses" onclick="clickedAddList()">
<input id="button2" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="directions(1, false, false, false, false)">
<input id='button3' type='button' value='Reset' onclick='startOver()'>
```

Comment: @DiaanLast Check the demo

Comment: Master, how to show marker if I do click on the button input process?